# Intersection of two vectors in two dimension

Tags: vectors

I have read few posts about vector intersection, but I am unable to understand them. So, wanted to ask a new question with specifically my needs.

I am trying to find the intersection of two 2 D vectors. So, my first approach was to simply change the vector into lines and find their solutions.

But my problem is I would like to find the intersection of vectors and not the lines. Below diagram shows the points ( . and ° ) as the origin of the vector.

```
.
 \        /
  \      /
   \    °
```

For example the above two vectors do not intersect, even if they are extrapolated in the direction of the vector.

However, the below one will intersect if its extrapolated in the direction of the vectors.

```
.          .
 \        /
  \      /
   \
```

Is there any way, one can find if the above vectors will intersect or not?

Comment: Just to clarify: You want the intersection of the two rays generated by the vectors, not the line, correct? The intersection of two vectors is undefined as far as I know, unless you view them as sets in which case they must be identical.

Comment: @max_zorn yes, exactly, I would like the intersection of the two rays generated by the vectors. Can you please post this as an answer and elaborate a little bit, why is it undefined? I am unable to understand your second statement

Comment: Each vector can be represented as $p_i+s_iq_i$, where $p_i$ is the start point, $q_i$ is the direction vector, and $s_i$ is a distance along the direction.  Solve for  both $s_i$.  If both positive the rays intersect, otherwise they do not.

Comment: @herbsteinberg can you please give a small example with real values, by posting as an answer?

Comment: How are your “vectors” specified?

Answer (score 1):

Two examples:
$p_1=(0,0),q_1=(1,1),\ \ p_2=(2,0),q_2=(0,1)$
$p_1=(0,0),q_1=(1,1),\ \ p_2=(2,1),q_2=(0,-1)$
The first example will have positive values for both s's.  The second example will have a negative value for $s_2$.

I'll let you do the arithmetic.